# Opting into the AI banner for AI generated content

Tags: discussion, answers

Should we [opt into the AI banner for answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395881/adding-a-banner-around-ai-generated-content) for AI content?

There are three options to consider

- Not making any change at all.
- Adding the following banner text to the answer box: **Reminder**: Answers generated by Artificial Intelligence tools are not allowed on Veganism & Vegetarianism. Learn more
- Adding the following text to the answer box: **Reminder**: Answers generated by Artificial Intelligence tools must be cited on Veganism & Vegetarianism. Learn more

Logged in users can dismiss the banner and it will then never appear again for you.

Note that we have had AI answers here and we (your moderators) have deleted them because they are both low quality i.e. they don't answer the question in any resonable manner and they have not cited their origin as AI generated.

For instance an AI answer we deleted to a question about being a vegetarian bodybuilder suggested that one of the ways to do that was to eat fish and chicken.

Answer (score 1):

Upvote this answer if you think we should add the following banner text to the answer box: **Reminder**: Answers generated by Artificial Intelligence tools are not allowed on Veganism & Vegetarianism. Learn more

If you think we should do something else I encourage you to write another answer.